# Cleaning Data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having values like \xc2\xa0Bluestone
\xc2\xa0CloudCherry
\xc2\xa0Footprints Education
in my dataset and i have been trying to remove these using some methods but unable to do so. PLease help out.
Till now i have tried:
1.df=df[df['Startup_Name']!='\xc2\xa0Ameyo']
2.Droping the rows having these values

Answer (score 1):

The C2AO is utf8 for nonbreaking space. Have you tried setting encoding=“utf_8” parameter for read_csv()?